# algorithm analysis - complex dependant nested loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

First of all, I know there are many questions like this on the site. But I think this case is a bit different.

Consider the following code:

```
int i, j, k;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){   
    for (j = 1; j <= (n-i); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (k = 1; k <= (i-j); k++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

What would be the time complexity of this code? It seems like O(n^2) to me but I can't justify it properly.

How our professor told us to compute complexity is just by adding all the summations together from every line.

$$
(n+1) + \sum_{j=1}^{N-i} + \sum_{j=1}^{N-i} + \sum_{k=1}^{i-j} + \sum_{k=1}^{i-j} + n
$$

However, I've never seen examples with summations like $\sum_{j=1}^{N-i}$, It's always either $\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}$ or some constant number being subtracted from N, which is easier to sum. So, How would I solve this? And is it O(n^2)?

Comment: There are two parts here. 1) Derive the correct sums. "Adding all the summations together" is vague; nested loops lead to nested sums. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). What you wrote down there doesn't make much sense; what's $\sum + \sum$? How do you get four sums from three loops? 2) Simplify the sums. They are particularly easy here, especially with a formulary at hand (e.g. the TCS Cheat Sheet). For help on simplifying sums, please hit [math.SE].

Comment: Community votes, please: Seems like a duplicate of our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) to me.

Comment: Hint for the sums: Sometimes reversing the order of summation can lead to an easily recognized form.

Comment: Are you sure that your professor wrote this ?

Comment: I suspect that you also incorrectly copied the code, because the presence of j in the third for loop is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

The number of print statements executed is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-i} 1\right) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{i-(n-i+1)} 1\right) + 1 \right],
$$
where the second sum is zero if $1 > i-(n-i+1)$.

The running time is proportional to the number of print statements, so it remains to compute the value of the expression above, or at least to give a good estimate. This I leave to you.

Comment: When I submitted the assignment, I got a equation very close to your equation there, Exactly, It was $\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-i} 1\right) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{i-(n-i)} 1\right)\right]$ and I solved it to $n(n+1)/2$ Which seems perfect to me but I still got 3/10 on it.

Comment: What he wants is a "line by line analysis" which I don't really understand how to perform. That's why the confused/non-sensical equation in the question. The most ridiculous thing was when he tried to explain that the second inner loop never runs, given any value of n, i, or j afterwards in the class.

Comment: You'll have to ask your professor for what he means by "line by line analysis". As for your solution, I'm not 100% sure it's correct, though the expression is certainly $\Theta(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

For better analysis the code, you can rewrite loop that use variable $k$ in terms of $n,i$ not $j$:

```
  int i, j, k;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){   
        for (j = 1; j <= (n-i); j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    
        for (k = 1; k <= (i-(n-i+1)); k++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Let $T(n)$ be time complexity of code. Therefore our code have two disjoint inner loop that displayed by the following summation (suppose each operation `System.out.print` need constant time, notice that, the inner loop with variable $j$ has the cost $(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i$), so:

$$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{i-n+i-1}\mathcal{O}(1)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2i-n-1}\mathcal{O}(1)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-n-1)=\Theta(n^2)+\mathcal{O}(n^2)$$
$$=\Theta(n^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us work out an example with $n=5$.

The outer loop is executed with $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Thus the first inner loop executes $4+3+2+1+0$ `print`'s. And the second inner loop $0+0+0+2+4$ `print`'s.

For $n=6$, we have $5+4+3+2+1+0$ `print`'s. And the second inner loop $0+0+0+1+3+5$ `print`'s.

We can easily generalize and get the counts $n$ (outer), $\dfrac{(n-1)n}2$ (first inner) and $\dfrac{n^2-1}4$ or $\dfrac{n^2}4$ depending on the parity of $n$ (second inner).